# how to use raw sql in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use raw SQL in Django. But what I import is PyMysql. So it seems that I cannot use the raw method. Can someone suggest how to solve this problem? Sorry, my English is poor.

Thanks, everyone

```
def home(request,*args,**kwargs):  
    blog = models.Blog.objects.filter(site = kwargs['site']).select_related('user').first()    
    tag_list = blog.tag.all()  
    article_list = blog.article_set.order_by("-nid").all()  
    date_list = blog.article_set.raw('select nid, count(nid) as num,strftime("%Y-%m",create_time) as ctime from repository_article group by strftime("%Y-%m",create_time)')  
    category_list = blog.category_set.all()  
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'blog':blog,'tag_list':tag_list,'category_list':category_list,'article_list':article_list,'date_list':date_list})
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list of dates? `blog.article_set.values_list('create_time', flat=True)`

Comment: No,i want to get this effect: 2017-02 2017-03 2017-04 and use the time to classify the content, ty sir. And django can not use the strftime method,so maybe i need to use raw sql.